# Android How to know transfered object size?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I have an app that transfer serializable object via bluetooth.

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int bytes;

// Keep listening to the InputStream while connected
while (true)
{
    try
    {
        // Read from the InputStream
        bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
        // manage bytes
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "disconnected", e);
        connectionLost();
        break;
    }
}
```

I need a next scenario :

- client push object to server
- server read bytes related to buffer size( in my case - 1024 bytes)
- server deserialize bytes into my object.

So,
**How i can know am i read `whole object or just a part of him`?**

P.S. Object may have big size, for ex - more than 100mb.

Comment: Have you considered transmitting a bit of metadata first? You could just specify that the first 4 bytes transmitted are an int that represents how many bytes the object contains.

Comment: @soong **why 4 bytes**, why not more? I have no limit to object size. It may be 100mb, 1000mb or bigger.

Comment: 'Client push object to server ' how? What technology are you using for transferring objects?

Comment: @Jakombo You could do 8 and store it in a long, but consider that 4 bytes gives you 2^32 bytes that you could specify - you'll be limited to 4 GB with 32 bits to store a size.  Alternately, you could do something like what WebSockets do and have a special value that indicates a significantly larger size, which follows. (see https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6455#section-5.2)

Comment: @Jakombo I can see for myself that you're using sockets. I'm asking what technology you are using *over* the socket to send objects. Sockets can only send bytes. Possible answers include Java Serialization, JSON, XML, ...

Answer (score 0):

You say you're sending serializable objects, by which I understand that you are using `ObjectOutputStream.writeObject().`

In which case you shouldn't be reading bytes at all, you should be using `ObjectInputStream.readObject().`

Comment: No, i convert object to byte[] sequence and write them to socket out stream.

Comment: Sigh. Convert it ***how***? Three times of asking now. If you don't tell us how the data is formed, or at least the protocol it uses, you cannot rationally expect an answer to this question.

Comment: Yes i convert to bytes with ObjectOutputStream.

Comment: So therefore you should be reading with `ObjectInputStream,` as I said in this answer. You're barking up the wrong tree.

Answer (score -1):

It's not the answer, just a proposal(suggestion).

What if i use a markup bytes for detect `BEGIN` and `END` of object?

For example :

```
final byte BEGIN = 0b00000000;
final byte END = 0b00001111;

byte[] BEGIN_OBJECT_BLOCK = new byte[1024];
byte[] END_OBJECT_BLOCK = new byte[1024];

for(int i=0; i<1024; i++) {
    BEGIN_OBJECT_BLOCK[i] = BEGIN;
}
//send BEGIN_OBJECT_BLOCK

byte[] tmpArray = new byte[1024];
// split object into blocks of 1024 bytes
// for each block -> send to server

for(int i=0; i<1024; i++) {
    END_OBJECT_BLOCK[i] = END;
}
//send END_OBJECT_BLOCK
```

1) How about this idea? 
 
2) What the negative side of this?

 3) What is the probability\chance of that my `BEGIN_OBJECT_BLOCK` **will be equals** to `byte sequence(byte[1024])` in object?

Comment: 1. It won't work. 2. It won't work. 3. Non-zero, which is sufficient to say it won't work. You need to stop posting your own guesswork and start answering the questions you're being asked here properly.